# Random testimonials with images

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm looking to showcase a selection of testimonials to display on my homepage. I want only a single testimonial to display at one time. The plan is for this to be randomised when the page is refreshed.

I want the testimonials to have a quote, the author and a photo of the author. Managed to get random testimonials before using a plugin but I like the idea of having pictures to link a face to the quote.

I've created a static version of what I'm hoping to do.

```
<div id="right_sidebar">
<div class="testimonials">
<div class="ref-picture"></div>
<blockquote>
<cite><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eget vestibulum elit. Cras pretium, dui sed egestas elementum, augue eros mattis erat, quis porta diam urna vitae lacus.</p>
</cite>
<div class="author">Paul Scholes - Manchester United</div>
</blockquote>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.testimonials {
width: 218px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: "adelle",serif;
margin-top: 13px;
padding-top: 10px;
position: relative;
}

.ref-picture {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 75px;
background: url('images/testimonial1.jpg') no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 59px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
z-index: 2;
}

.testimonials .author {
padding: 10px;
padding-top: 0px;
font-family: "adelle",serif;
color: #dedede!important;
font-size: 11px;
border: 0px;
}

.testimonials blockquote {
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 24px;
font-family: Lato;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #333;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 5px;
background: black;
position: relative;
top: 50px;
}

.testimonials blockquote cite {
font-size: 11px;
}

.testimonials blockquote cite p {
line-height: 16px!important;
padding: 70px 10px 20px 10px;
color: white;
}
```

Firstly, would this be doable? If so, anyone got any suggestions on how I'd do this? Maybe some sort of JQuery script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer your 3 questions: Yes, use javascript, jQuery will make it less verbose but is a bit overkill for such a simple function.

Comment: Are you planning on using the static HTML or is it going to be dynamicly generated through wordpress?

Comment: @PeterStuart I want it to display them dynamically. The static HTML was only as an example.

Answer (score 1):

PJ,

Checkout: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-random-posts-in-wordpress/

You can add additional info like excerpt and author by using these from the Wordpress Codex.

Author: http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

Excerpt: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

I hope that helps!

Cheers

Comment: So would I create each testimonial as a post?

Comment: Yes, and have them all in the same category. This way you could utilize the testimonials in other ways down the road, like an rss feed or something.

Comment: Also, from wpbeginner.com down in the comments someone mentions a method to choose the category that posts are pulled from.

Answer (score 1):

Put the testimonials in an array:

```
var testimonials = [
  { picture: 'images/testimonial1.jpg', cite: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', author: 'Paul Scholes - Manchester United' },
  { picture: 'images/testimonial2.jpg', cite: 'consectetur adipiscing elit.', author: 'Paul Scholes - Manchester United' },
  { picture: 'images/testimonial3.jpg', cite: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', author: 'Paul Scholes - Manchester United' },
  { picture: 'images/testimonial4.jpg', cite: 'consectetur adipiscing elit.', author: 'Paul Scholes - Manchester United' },
  { picture: 'images/testimonial5.jpg', cite: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', author: 'Paul Scholes - Manchester United' },
  { picture: 'images/testimonial6.jpg', cite: 'consectetur adipiscing elit.', author: 'Paul Scholes - Manchester United' }
];
```

Pick one by random:

```
var testimonial = testimonials[Math.floor(Math.random() * testimonials.length)];
```

Put the details in the elements. Here you could make use of jQuery to easily find and update the elements:

```
$('.testimonials .ref-picture').css('backgroundImage', 'url('+testimonial.picture+')');
$('.testimonials cite p').text(testimonial.cite);
$('.testimonials .author').text(testimonial.author);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/wme4V/

Comment: Thanks @Guffa for the answer. Tried executing this but I'm such a novice at coding that I've failed miserably :(

Comment: @pjthefarmer: Fixed the spelling of the classes, and added a period that was missing. I added a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I am all for jQuery. You can use following randomize plugin to randomize the testimonials. Read more about jQuery [here](http://jquery.com/)

```
(function($) {

$.fn.randomize = function(childElem) {
  return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var elems = $this.children(childElem);

      elems.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); });  

      $this.remove(childElem);  

      for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++)
        $this.append(elems[i]);      

  });    
}
})(jQuery);
```